# How to calculate the cell constant for a flow-through conductivity cell?

Tags: electricity

I need to design a flow-through cell but I don't know how to calculate the cell constant for such a cell. It needs to have 2 ring electrodes within an insulating tube (see pic below). One of the electrodes will have a voltage applied while the other will measure the current. I know that the cell constant for a parallel plate cell is L/A while the cell constant for a concentric cylinder cell is ln(r2/r1)/2(pi)L as explained in another forum post: [How to calculate resistivity from this cell design?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/428623/how-to-calculate-resistivity-from-this-cell-design/428647#428647). I think it's difficult to calculate the cell constant for the flow-through case as all parts of the surfaces of the electrodes will not be the same distance apart. I would appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: This might be better suited for the physics stack exchange.

Comment: The highest rated answer (not the selected one) is that "you don't, you calibrate it with a standard solution". My second choice would be to do it numerically with a finite element analysis (assuming this is a real problem and not a homework assignment).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Hi, this is not a homework assignment, it's a project for my phd. I need to first design it before i can construct it and calibrate it. It's best to first have a theoretical approximation of the cell constant so i can design it. I was wondering if you explain how i would go about solving this numerically with FEA? thank you.

Comment: Do you have access to something like Comsol or ANSYS? I mean you could do it from scratch (I did back in University), but there are modern tools available now.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yh i have comsol. I didn't know you could use it to do this though. Thank you.

Comment: A general note- it would be nice sometimes if people filled in at least a bit of their profile, makes it easier many times to tailor a response.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.comsol.com/video/modeling-electrochemical-systems-comsol-multiphysics) is a webinar on using Comsol to model electrochemical systems.

I think in practice you'll get close making some simplifying assumptions and then calibrate it with a reference solution.

I did some commercial conductivity instrumentation for RO systems used in hospital medical dialysis installations, and the conductivity cell response has some 'interesting' dependencies on both measuring voltage and frequency.

Comment: Thanks a lot Spehro